# using 'of' or 'for'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

For the last few years i've always written the following sentence with for:

> ... the value **for** the thing.

But now I've been writing a lot of documentation and I've started wondering if I should use of or for in this case.

the sentences i'm writing are like this:

> Gets or sets the configuration **for** a specific port. 
>   Gets or sets the current state of the access provider **for** a specific port.

so my question: Is 'for' in this case the correct word to use or should it be:

> Gets or sets the configuration **of** a specific port. 
>   Gets or sets the current state of the access provider **of** a specific port.

Comment: Closely related, [“Of” and “For” Before “-ing”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62633/of-and-for-before-ing).

Answer (score 1):

"Configuration for..." means a configuration that is suitable for use.

"Configuration of..." means the configuration in actual use.

Comment: so if i were to set it i should use for and if i were to get it i should use of?

Comment: No. You get or set the configuration **of** a port. However, you create (design) a configuration **for** a port.